# Can we disable right clicking on Anchor Tag in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, contextmenu

I have a requirement where right clicking on document name in grid opens a customized context menu (using Smartgwt). I had to implement hyperlink so I created an anchor tag (which calls a JSNI method which in turn calls a GWT method and which again in turn calls an applet method to open a document and stream it to the server). If you don't right click on the document name everything works fine and custom context menu opens. But when you click on document name then the default link menu with open, open in new tab comes and due to clash between smartgwt context menu and this menu some Javascript Null Pointer Exception is thrown in my client console.

Now is there any way that I can hide the default link menu (on anchor tag) so that it doesn't appear in my grid even when anyone clicks on the document name?

Comment: can you create [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for the same?

Comment: is jsfiddle a library like jquery/prototype-js? We can't use any more external library and that too for such a small requirement

Comment: jsfiddle is not a library; it's just a way to show your code like codepad, collabedit, or cloud9.

Comment: I didn't still get what it is :( but I would prefer a simpler way in html/javascript. And can you post as an answer what changes I have to do by taking any simple example with an anchor tag?

Comment: Just to check: Is the rightclick javascript function returning false to the anchor? If not, please do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

by adding this to anchor tag you can disable right click `oncontextmenu="return false"`

Comment: Very small and clean. I was guessing something like this but didn't get. Thanks.

Comment: :) its helped me too at multiple places

Comment: Excellent Job, Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Just some simple example to show that it's tottaly doable: http://jsfiddle.net/3dLW3/6/
(Chrome 18)

Comment: No the example uses jquery and can't implement jquery for such a small requirement. The marked answer was simple and it works!

Comment: It just uses jQuery to illustrate that it can be done. Of course you can do that with vanilla javascript as well. Cheers! :)